# Rails editing users as an admin on one page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4.0.1 and Devise 3.3.2.

I'm trying to create a page where an admin can update multiple users' roles. Something like:

manage.html.erb:

```
<% @user.each do |user| %>
  <%= form_for user, :html => { :multipart => true} do |f| %>
    <%= user.profile_name %>
    <%= user.right %>
    <%= f.label :right %><br />
    <%= f.radio_button :right, "None" %>User
    <%= f.radio_button :right, "Administrator" %>Administrator</div>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

user_controller.rb:

```
def manage
  @user = User.all
  respond_to do |format|
    @user.update(user_params)
  end
end

private
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:id, :right)
end
```

But I got an error. As I understand, it can't understand the users' id. Any ideas or tutorials?

```
Started GET "/manage" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-24 22:22:23 +0600
Processing by UserController#update as HTML 
Completed 400 Bad Request in 15ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param not found: user):
 app/controllers/user_controller.rb:46:in `user_params'
 app/controllers/user_controller.rb:39:in `block in update'
 app/controllers/user_controller.rb:38:in `update'
```

Comment: param not found: user

Comment: please post the error in the log.

Comment: @Donovan done. Maybe that's because i'm trying to fetch all users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of issues here... but here's where I think your first challenge is:

It looks like you're trying to do both the **display** of the form and handle the **submission** of the form in the same action. That's not going to work.

The rails conventions have pairs of actions: new+create and edit+update. `new` and `edit` only take care of **displaying** the forms, and `create` and `update` handle the **submission** of the forms.

So the first thing you need to do is have two actions in your controller. One will assign `@user` then render the view you have, and the other will use the parameters that you get when you submit the form and do something with those parameters to update the users, like what you're trying to do currently in the `render` block in your controller.

The other problems you're going to run into next are:

- Using `form_for` is not going to post to your custom route unless you make changes to the code you have here
- You're rendering a form for each user, so you're going to have a submit button for each user, but it sounds like you really want **one** form for all the users with one submit button
- Updating multiple records is more complicated than just calling one `update` method on all of them and passing in all the params

[This railscast on editing multiple records](http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple?view=asciicast) will probably be useful.

Answer (score 1):

When you submit this form, it will use either the `create` or `update` methods in your controller, and not `manage` unless you've specifically added a `PATCH` route for it.

So, you'll need to be sure you're using `user_params` in those methods.

Additionally, unless it's a typo in your question, you're missing an `<% end %>` in `manage.html.erb`

Comment: i changed in controller to update method, but it's still doesn't work and returns me the same error